# How to reverse url with optional fields arguments in django?

Tags: django, django-urls

I have an url with an optionnal argument:

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    'my_app.views',
    url('schedule/(?P<calendar_id>\d+)/(?:month(?P<relative_month>[\+,\-]\d)/)$',
    'attribute_event',name='attribute_event')
)
```

In my template I have a link:

```
{% url attribute_event calendar.id %}
```

But I have an error saying the url can't be reversed with these args. Must I use 2 url regex entry and url names?!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

only possible if you split it into two urls:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('my_app.views',
    url('schedule/(?P<calendar_id>\d+)/month(?P<relative_month>[\+,\-]\d)/$',
        'attribute_event', name='attribute_event_relative'),
    url('schedule/(?P<calendar_id>\d+)/)$', 
        'attribute_event', name='attribute_event'),
)
```

in template:

```
{% url attribute_event calendar.id %}

or

{% url attribute_event_relative calendar.id '+1' %}
```

your view:

```
def attribute_event(request, calendar_id, relative_month=None):
    pass
```

Comment: Hoo damned sorry, in fact my error was in my regex, I forgot "?" as [-2] char... `'schedule/(?P<calendar_id>\d+)/(?:month(?P<relative_month>[\+,\-]\d)/)?$'` So I don't need multiple entries.

Comment: (As long as I sepcify all args in template even to None)

Answer (score 2):

Has to be this ticket:

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/9176